# does marklogic database support stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, marklogic

Does **MarkLogic** support stored procedure?  Like can you save some **XQuery** sentence on server and call it?  I googled but did not find interesting things.

Answer (score 2):

You can put what is called an "XQuery Module" in either a modules database or on the file system of the server running MarkLogic.  By pointing the "modules" and "root" setting of an app server at the folder containing this module it becomes executable through that app server.  For example.  If you place a module called hello.xqy at "C:\myfiles\hello.xqy"  and then create a MarkLogic HTTP server on port 8080 with modules: (filesystem) and root: "C:\myfiles\"  that script will execute when you go to "http:\localhost:8080\hello.xqy" with a web browser.

The evaluation of the syntax of these modules is cached by MarkLogic server, so in some ways it is very much like a stored procedure.

The actual MarkLogic documentation explains this pretty well: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/import_modules#id_45509